# How to give date format to react-csv column

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, export-to-csv

I am trying to export data as csv file . I am using `react-csv` library for it everything is working fine but I am face to date format. I tried but didn't find any proper solution . could someone please help me .

**Code**

```
 headers = [
    {
      label: "id",
      key: "id"
    },
    {
      label: "Type",
      key: "ptype"
    },
    {
      label: "Sub Type",
      key: "subtype"
    },
    {
      label: "Date",
      key: moment("createdAt").format("YYYY-MM-DD")
    },
}
```

It not working it give me empty column when I write key with just `createdAt` it give me date in this format `2019-09-13T06:34:33.000Z` I want date in readable format

Comment: Try the momentjs conversion outside the object,store it to a variable and use that variable inside the object
Post the full code.

Comment: CreatedAt should be a variable, Currently its a string inside moment()

Comment: Can you post more of your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot format cell in your `header` array. `header` array is just to represent the column name in `csv` file.

You need to actually format your data before providing to `CSVLink`.

```
data = data.map(row => ({...row, createdAt: moment(row.createdAt).format("YYYY-MM-DD")}))
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bv1x7s)

Answer (score 1):

transform your data before you use json2csv or whatever:

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, ptype: "a", subtype: "x", createdAt: "2019-09-13T06:34:33.000Z"},
  { id: 2, ptype: "b", subtype: "y", createdAt: "2019-09-13T06:34:33.000Z"},
  { id: 3, ptype: "c", subtype: "z", createdAt: "2019-09-13T06:34:33.000Z" }
].map(item => {
  return {
    ...item, 
    ...{createdAt: moment(item.createdAt).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}
  };
});
console.log(data)
// .... here your code
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Works. Look at the output.